# TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable in my code

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, error-handling

I have written two python codes. Code 1 is showing error of 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable. But when I comment some section which is in code 2, program runs successfully. I am new to this language so I can't figure out what the problem is. Is there some syntax error? Can anyone resolve this issue?

Code 1:

```
import numpy as np
import csv

x = np.genfromtxt("boston_housing.csv",dtype=float,delimiter=',',skip_header=1,usecols = (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12))

xx = x
y = np.genfromtxt("boston_housing.csv",dtype=float,delimiter=',',skip_header=1,usecols = (13))


ave = np.zeros(13)
sum = np.zeros(13)
mn = [x[0][0],x[0][1],x[0][2],x[0][3],x[0][4],x[0][5],x[0][6],x[0][7],x[0][8],x[0][9],x[0][10],x[0][11],x[0][12]]
mx = [x[0][0],x[0][1],x[0][2],x[0][3],x[0][4],x[0][5],x[0][6],x[0][7],x[0][8],x[0][9],x[0][10],x[0][11],x[0][12]]
for row in x:
    for i in range(0,13):
        sum[i] = sum[i] + row[i]
        mn[i] = min(mn[i],row[i])
        mx[i] = max(mx[i],row[i])

alpha = 0.001
theta = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
for ll in range(0,1):
    temp = []
    grad0 = (1.0/506)*sum([(theta[0] + theta[1]*xx[i][0] + theta[2]*xx[i][1] + theta[3]*xx[i][2] + theta[4]*xx[i][3] + theta[5]*xx[i][4] + theta[6]*xx[i][5]
                        + theta[7]*xx[i][6] + theta[8]*xx[i][7] + theta[9]*xx[i][8] + theta[10]*xx[i][9] + theta[11]*xx[i][10] + theta[12]*xx[i][11]
                        + theta[13]*xx[i][12] - y[i]) for i in range (506)])
    temp.append(theta[0] - (alpha * grad0))
    for j in range(1,14):
        grad0 = (1.0/506)*sum([(theta[0] + theta[1]*xx[i][0] + theta[2]*xx[i][1] + theta[3]*xx[i][2] + theta[4]*xx[i][3] + theta[5]*xx[i][4] + theta[6]*xx[i][5]
                            + theta[7]*xx[i][6] + theta[8]*xx[i][7] + theta[9]*xx[i][8] + theta[10]*xx[i][9] + theta[11]*xx[i][10] + theta[12]*xx[i][11]
                            + theta[13]*xx[i][12] - y[i])*xx[i][j-1] for i in range (506)])
        temp.append(theta[j] - (alpha * grad0))
    theta = temp
yy = [0.02501,35,4.15,1,0.77,8.78,81.3,2.5051,24,666,17,382.8,11.48]
ans = 0
for i in range(0,13):
    ans = ans + (yy[i] * theta[i+1])
ans = ans + theta[0]
print(theta)
print(ans)
```

Code 2:

```
import numpy as np
import csv

x = np.genfromtxt("boston_housing.csv",dtype=float,delimiter=',',skip_header=1,usecols = (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12))
xx = x
y = np.genfromtxt("boston_housing.csv",dtype=float,delimiter=',',skip_header=1,usecols = (13))

"""
ave = np.zeros(13)
sum = np.zeros(13)
mn = [x[0][0],x[0][1],x[0][2],x[0][3],x[0][4],x[0][5],x[0][6],x[0][7],x[0][8],x[0][9],x[0][10],x[0][11],x[0][12]]
mx = [x[0][0],x[0][1],x[0][2],x[0][3],x[0][4],x[0][5],x[0][6],x[0][7],x[0][8],x[0][9],x[0][10],x[0][11],x[0][12]]
for row in x:
    for i in range(0,13):
        sum[i] = sum[i] + row[i]
        mn[i] = min(mn[i],row[i])
        mx[i] = max(mx[i],row[i])
"""
alpha = 0.001
theta = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
for ll in range(0,1):
    temp = []
    grad0 = (1.0/506)*sum([(theta[0] + theta[1]*xx[i][0] + theta[2]*xx[i][1] + theta[3]*xx[i][2] + theta[4]*xx[i][3] + theta[5]*xx[i][4] + theta[6]*xx[i][5]
                        + theta[7]*xx[i][6] + theta[8]*xx[i][7] + theta[9]*xx[i][8] + theta[10]*xx[i][9] + theta[11]*xx[i][10] + theta[12]*xx[i][11]
                        + theta[13]*xx[i][12] - y[i]) for i in range (506)])
    temp.append(theta[0] - (alpha * grad0))
    for j in range(1,14):
        grad0 = (1.0/506)*sum([(theta[0] + theta[1]*xx[i][0] + theta[2]*xx[i][1] + theta[3]*xx[i][2] + theta[4]*xx[i][3] + theta[5]*xx[i][4] + theta[6]*xx[i][5]
                            + theta[7]*xx[i][6] + theta[8]*xx[i][7] + theta[9]*xx[i][8] + theta[10]*xx[i][9] + theta[11]*xx[i][10] + theta[12]*xx[i][11]
                            + theta[13]*xx[i][12] - y[i])*xx[i][j-1] for i in range (506)])
        temp.append(theta[j] - (alpha * grad0))
    theta = temp
yy = [0.02501,35,4.15,1,0.77,8.78,81.3,2.5051,24,666,17,382.8,11.48]
ans = 0
for i in range(0,13):
    ans = ans + (yy[i] * theta[i+1])
ans = ans + theta[0]
print(theta)
print(ans)
```

Comment: Please provide the full traceback. Additionally, you definitely want to check out the [numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/quickstart.html).

Comment: Your question is being downvoted because it is missing important information.  You have included your code, which is great, but it would be even better if (as Max Powers requests) you included the full traceback (i.e. the *complete* error message).  The traceback shows valuable information about the error, including the line that triggered the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this line near the beginning of the first script:

```
sum = np.zeros(13)
```

That shadows the builtin function [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), which you try to call here:

```
    grad0 = (1.0/506)*sum([(theta[0] + theta[1]*xx[i][0] + theta[2]*xx[i][1] + theta[3]*xx[i][2] + theta[4]*xx[i][3] + theta[5]*xx[i][4] + theta[6]*xx[i][5]
                    + theta[7]*xx[i][6] + theta[8]*xx[i][7] + theta[9]*xx[i][8] + theta[10]*xx[i][9] + theta[11]*xx[i][10] + theta[12]*xx[i][11]
                    + theta[13]*xx[i][12] - y[i]) for i in range (506)])
```

You have redefined `sum` to be a numpy array, and you are now trying to call `sum()`.  That generates the error, because numpy arrays are not callable.  For example,

```
In [7]: x
Out[7]: array([ 1.,  2.,  3.])

In [8]: x(99)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-05cea57e85d3> in <module>()
----> 1 x(99)

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

To fix it, change the name of the `sum` array to something like `total`.